# import one piece of code into another piece of code

Tags: python, import

I wrote a piece of code called quadForm.py that solves a quadratic formula. I am trying to place that code into another file where it will output the values. I am new to python and not sure on how to do this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the python `import` statement. Let us assume you are using a function `solve()` defined in quadForm.py in another file main.py in the same directory. Then in main.py you would write the following

```
import quadForm

quadForm.solve()
```

or if you want to call the function `solve` directly without using the `quadForm` prefix

```
from quadForm import solve

solve()
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is put the the files in the same directory and add,

```
from quadForm import *
```

to the other file. Then you can use any function that you defined in quadForm.py (using def) in the other file.